# select2: Is it possible to pass custom input and access it in methods

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I want to pass custom property while creating select2. Example (my custom property being `myFilterEnabled`):

```
$('#mySelId2').select2({
  myFilterEnabled: false, //Pass my initial state
  query: function(query) {
    var res = {
      results: CityFilter.cities
    };
    query.callback(res);
  }
});
```

And use it in the query or render functions. Like:

```
$('#mySelId2').select2({
  myFilterEnabled: false,
  query: function(query) {
    var fltEnabled = this.myFilterEnabled; //Read current state
    var res = {
      results: fltEnabled ? [] : CityFilter.cities
    };
    query.callback(res);
  }
});
```

This is so that, there is an initial state for the variable. But, it can change externally, and I want to check that state during each re-render/query.

**Edit: Seems I made a mistake before posting. Above code seems to work. I am planning to add a common prefix like 'my' or 'myProj' so that it doesn't conflict with any variables of select2 itself.**

Edit2: As mentioned, passing initial state and reading current state are working. I still need a way to change that state from outside. If select2 doesn't have a method for that I could set a data attribute on the element.

Comment: Why don't to set the data property on element it self and use (`$(element).data('myFilterEnabled', 'some-value')` and get `$(element).data('myFilterEnabled')` )

Comment: How could the library accept your custom property?

Comment: @maximusツ Thanks. I'll try that.

Comment: Sorry, looks like I did a typo in my local version. What code I posted seems to be working!!

Comment: I am able to access and set my custom property from outside like this: $('#s2id_<myId>').data('select2').opts.myFilterEnabled = true;

Answer (score 0):

This is the full cycle that I wanted:

> Set custom state -> Read custom state during query/render -> Change custom state on user action -> Trigger re-render on state change

This is how I managed to do it as of now:

1) I can pass a custom parameter in options while setting up `select2`

```
$('#mySelId2').select2({
            myFilterEnabled: false,
            query: function(query){ ...
```

2) I am able to read the custom parameter within the callbacks as

```
this.myFilterEnabled
```

3) I can set the custom parameter from outside as

```
$('#s2id_<myId>').data('select2').opts.myFilterEnabled = true;
```

3) After setting the property as shown above, i want `select2` to
    re-apply the `query` function. I can `trigger` `change` on
    `input.select2-input`. But, there is a check to prevent re-execution
    of query while the text remains the same. So, I go a step further
    and call the `updateResults` function with a 'true' argument. That
    forces `updateResult` to proceed to run `query` again. Example:

```
    $('#s2id_<myId>').data('select2').updateResults(true);
```